# Hidden input field didnot show the correct value which was access from views.py in Django

Tags: python, django

Before I asked this question, I have searched online and found similar solutions. However, it does not work for my case.

I would like to pass the hidden input value in views.py  but it didn't show the right value.
when I hardcoded the value it passes the correct one but when I passed the value which was access from one of the functions of views.py it didn't show the correct value in the console.

here is my html template where i access the value in hidden input tag

```
<label > <h1>All grade:</h1></label>

<form action="show_topics" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}
{% for cat in show_grades %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"> 
            <label><h5 class="card-title" style="color: hotpink">{{cat.grade}}</h5></label>
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="gradeid" value="{{to.grade}}"> -->
            <button  class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="classname" value="{{cat.grade}}" ><h4>View Class</h4></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="ids" id="idss" value="{{cat.id}}">

            <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>-->             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %} 
</form>
```

view.py

(from that function retrieved the value which is used in hidden input field)

```
def add_grade(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    teacher_id=request.POST.get('submit')
    #tech_id=int(teacher_id)
    print("teacher id retrieved")
    print(teacher_id)
    print("===")
    #print(tech_id)
    grade = request.POST.get('addgrade')
    # classes=request.POST.get('class')
    grade = Add_Grade(grade=grade, username_id=teacher_id)
    grade.save()

    show_grades = Add_Grade.objects.raw("Select * from Add_Grade where username_id = %s",teacher_id)
    context={
        'show_grades':show_grades,

    }

    #allgrade=Add_Grade.objects.all()
    return render(request,'teacher_dashboard.html',context)
```

access/pass the hidden value in this function

```
def show_topics(request):
if request.method== "POST":
    classname=request.POST.get('classname')
    classid=request.POST.get('ids')
    print("is correct value pass")
    print(classname)
    print(classid)
    print("-----")
    context={
        'classid':classid,
        'classname':classname,
        #'show_topics' : show_topics,
    }

    return render(request,'add_topic.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_grade(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    teacher_id=request.POST.get('gradeid')
    #tech_id=int(teacher_id)
    print("teacher id retrieved")
    print(teacher_id)
```

I've looked through your template not to find anything with the `name = "submit"` so I assume you needed the `name = "gradeid".`
See if this works

Comment: the add_grade() retrieved the user input from the other form in this template that i have not mentioned here and this function works fine. the problem is that i want to access the variable  show_grades (in add_grade() function) and used it in the template form mentioned above and want to access the value of id through {{cat.id}} in the hidden input tag because I need this value in the show_topics() but the hidden tag value did not show the correct value when i checked that by printing it on console in show_topics() .